# Udacity's exercise: superhero nuisance one-line answer?

Tags: python

I'm going through the Udacity "Intro to Computer Science" course coding with Python, and in Lesson 2 Problem Set (Optional 2) I encountered the following problem:

```
# Write a Python procedure fix_machine to take 2 string inputs
# and returns the 2nd input string as the output if all of its
# characters can be found in the 1st input string and "Give me
# something that's not useless next time." if it's impossible.
# Letters that are present in the 1st input string may be used
# as many times as necessary to create the 2nd string (you
# don't need to keep track of repeat usage).
```

My code:

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
  i = 0
  while i <= len(product)-1:
    if debris.find(product[i]) == -1:
      return "Give me something that's not useless next time."
    elif i == len(product)-1:
      return product
    else:
      i = i + 1
```

Now, what I'm curious about is that they say **it can be done in just one line**:

```
# BONUS: # 
# 5***** #  If you've graduated from CS101,
#  Gold  #  try solving this in one line.
# Stars! #
```

How would the one-line answer of this problem be like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def fix_machine(a, b):
  return set(a) >= set(b) and b or "Give me something that's not useless next time."
```

special thanks to @ajcr

PS: as @user2357112 mentioned, it will fail with empty strings.

```
def fix_machine(a, b):
  return b if set(a) >= set(b) else "Give me something that's not useless next time."
```

Comment: Should be `set(a) >= set(b)` to be true to the original question I think.

Comment: You should use a conditional expression (`true_option if condition else false_option`) instead of the and/or hack here. The and/or hack fails if `b` is empty.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, you could save one more line by turning the `def` into a `lambda` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
    return 'Give me something that\'s not useless  next time' if ''.join([i for i in product if i in debris]) != product else product
```

My attempt at the one line solution.

Answer (score -1):

my code:

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
### WRITE YOUR CODE HERE ###

    for s in product:
        if debris.find(s) == -1:
            return "Give me something that's not useless next time."
    return product
```

anyway,it gives me a "correct!"

Comment: The request is for a one-line answer.

Answer (score -1):

def count(debris,i):

```
if i in debris:
    return 0
else:
    return 1
```

def fix_machine(debris, product):

```
sum = 0
for i in range(0,len(product)):   
    sum = count(debris, product[i]) + sum
if sum == 0:
    return product
else
    return "Give me something that's not useless next time."
```